# How to implement Preference?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I am trying to use a Preference Screen. To do this I have a class that extends PreferenceFragmentCompat. Initially I wanted to use PreferenceFragment but it's deprecated, therefore know I have to use PreferenceFragmentCompat. Know to use this I have to add an implementation in my dependencies in my build.gradle file. This is my current dependencies:

```
    dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc02'
implementation 'com.android.support:preference-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.io:2.4'
}
```

Now this is the code for my fragment:

```
    public class ConfigFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {

public static ConfigFragment newInstance() {

    Bundle args = new Bundle();

    ConfigFragment fragment = new ConfigFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}


  @Override
  public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle bundle, String s) {
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
 }
}
```

I am currently getting this error in my Logcat:

> Error while Installing APK

In my Debug I am getting this error:

> 09-13 00:31:45.137 1613-5102/? E/AudioFlinger: createRecordTrack_l() initCheck failed -12; no control block?
>   09-13 00:31:45.140 2505-16972/? E/IAudioFlinger: createRecord returned error -12
>   09-13 00:31:45.140 2505-16972/? E/AudioRecord: AudioFlinger could not create record track, status: -12
>   09-13 00:31:45.140 2505-16972/? E/AudioRecord-JNI: Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed with status -12.
>   09-13 00:31:45.141 2505-16972/? E/android.media.AudioRecord: Error code -20 when initializing native AudioRecord object.
>
> Caused by: com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.exception.GsaIOException: Error code: 393238 | Buffer overflow, no available space.

It's interesting how I am not using AudioRecord and I still get this error. The errors I am getting showed after I added the preference implementation. How can I fix this or correctly implement PreferenceFragmentCompat?

Comment: That error is probably irrelevant to your actual issue. Check LogCat for an error message _exactly_ where the "error while installing APK" message pops up. Also try `./gradlew installDebug --verbose --stacktrace` to spit out more info.

Comment: I typed that into the terminal in Android studio and got > Unknown command-line option '--verbose'

Comment: I am also getting app installation failed error.

Comment: Sorry it's not `--verbose` it's `--debug`.